# Internet explorer horizontal coda nav out of position

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The whole image is clickable in Firefox / Chrome / Safari but in Internet Explorer it is only clickable to the right of the image.

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/cthm/work/

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function() {
    $(".slider1").codaSlider( {dynamicArrows: false, dynamicTabs: false} );        $(".slider1 .coda-nav-right-wrapper").mouseover(function() {
      $(".nav1").css("display","block");
    });
    $(".slider1 .coda-nav-right-wrapper").mouseout(function() {
      $(".nav1").css("display", "none");
    });
    $("#coda-nav-right-1 > a > .coda-nav-right-wrapper").mouseover(function() {
      $(".caption1").css("display", "inline");
    });         

    $("#coda-nav-right-1 > a > .coda-nav-right-wrapper").mouseout(function() {
      $(".caption1").css("display", "none");
    });
  });
</script>
```

CSS

```
#content .coda-nav-right-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 40;
  width: 900px;
  height: 450px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a block level element `<div>` inside an inline element `<a>`. This is not semantically valid for IE. So, giving a `display: block;` or `float: left;` for the `<a>` tag, fixes it.